# British Standard Steel BS5S82 propagation properties

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, steel

I am looking for propagation data for the BS5S82 material (case hardened). I checked in MMPDS and ESDU but to no avail. does anyone know where I can find this data? Or at least similar materials in terms of propagation properties? It will be a great help. Thank you.